# Why is VSCode refusing to build

Tags: json

Whenever I try to build a new project via 'dotnet new console' this is the error I get:
(see below)

My manually coded c# project too does not run, it just asks me which framework I ant to use (.net5 and .net core) and then nothing happens.. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Vscode, still the same thing, and I once had this question removed for not being accurate, I hope I get a solution this time :(

```
'0x00' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.Utf8JsonStreamReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.ReadStringDictionary(Utf8JsonStreamReader& reader)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.ReadLocalizationCatalog(Stream localizationStream, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.ReadWorkloadManifest(String manifestId, Stream manifestStream, Stream localizationStream, String informationalPath)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.LoadManifestsFromProvider(IWorkloadManifestProvider manifestProvider)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.Create(IWorkloadManifestProvider manifestProvider, String dotnetRootPath, String sdkVersion, String userProfileDir)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.TemplateLocator.TemplateLocator.GetDotnetSdkTemplatePackages(String sdkVersion, String dotnetRootPath, String userProfileDir)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.New.OptionalWorkloadProvider.GetAllTemplatePackagesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplatePackageManager.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<EnsureProvidersLoaded>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplatePackageManager.GetTemplatePackagesAsync(Boolean force, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplatePackageManager.UpdateTemplateCacheAsync(Boolean needsRebuild, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplatePackageManager.GetTemplatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.TemplateResolution.BaseTemplateResolver.GetTemplateGroupsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.TemplateResolution.InstantiateTemplateResolver.ResolveTemplatesAsync(INewCommandInput commandInput, String defaultLanguage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.TemplateInvocationCoordinator.CoordinateInvocationAsync(INewCommandInput commandInput, CancellationToken cancellationToken)       
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.EnterTemplateManipulationFlowAsync(INewCommandInput commandInput)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.ExecuteAsync(INewCommandInput commandInput)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.ActualRun(String commandName, ITemplateEngineHost host, ITelemetryLogger telemetryLogger, New3Callbacks callbacks, String[] args, String hivePath)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay I'll remove it right away